# What is the purpose of <template> usage in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use Vuetify 2.0 in my project and currently reading about [v-stepper](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) component which is used to display progress through numbered steps.

In the [playground example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers#playground) provided I see that they are using `<template>` element to wrap content of `v-stepper` component. HTML looks something like this (note: I removed unnecessary details):

```
<v-stepper>
  <template v-for="n in steps">
    <v-stepper-content
      :key="`${n}-content`"
      :step="n"
    >

    </v-stepper-content>
  </template>
</v-stepper>
```

Notice the `<template>` tag used. What is the purpose of it? When should I use it as opposed to just putting the `<v-stepper-content>` directly inside of `<v-stepper>`?

I've read a bit about  [element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) but I am not sure how to use it specifically with Vuetify (or more generally with Vue.Js or just pure HTML/CSS/JS for that matter).

Comment: Doesn't the original example have multiple children inside the `<template>`? For multiple children it's required to loop over all of them in a single loop: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### a `<template>` in the context of a `v-for` loop is an **organizational** item.

It does not get rendered by the browser. It is there to help with more complex rendering situations, where you don't want to limit yourself to a single element

In most cases you have a pretty straight forward mapping of items, each item in an array gets a `<li>` element. If this is the case, you're not likely to use this.

#### Here is an example of a problem where it might help...

Let's say you want to loop through an array of objects, and render a v-btn if the object is a button, and a v-image if the object is an image.

without template...

```html
  <span v-for="item in items">
    <v-btn v-if="item.isBtn"></v-btn>
    <v-img v-else-if="item.isImg"></v-img>
  </span>
```

The problem is that each item will be wrapped in the span.

```html
<span>
  <v-btn/>
</span>
<span>
  <v-img/>
</span>
<span>
  <v-btn/>
</span>
```

If you, however, use the `template` element, the wrapping element is no longer there.

```html
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <v-btn v-if="item.isBtn"></v-btn>
    <v-img v-else-if="item.isImg"></v-img>
  </template>
```

and you will get...

```html
  <v-btn/>
  <v-img/>
  <v-btn/>
```

You can also have it return multiple items in one instance of the loop.

in the vue docs at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt
it shows an example of rendering more than one item per iteration:

```html
<ul>
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <li>{{ item.msg }}</li>
    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

There are some other cases where this might be helpful but not likely something you come across on a daily basis.

---

### TL;DR;

#### Vue doesn't render the `<template>` element. It helps organize code chunk without the need of a single child element when looping

---

### part 2.

> > #### When should I use it as opposed to just putting the  directly inside of ?

Because the structure of vertical and horizontal steppers is different,  the vuetify authors used it in the playground to allow users to toggle it. The first level of template (`<template v-if="vertical">`) is used do determine whether the next level should render the `v-stepper-step` elements as vertical or as horizontal. The second level is used to do the iterating of items.

example:

vertical (step and content are siblings):

```html
<template>
  <v-stepper v-model="e6" vertical>
    <v-stepper-step :complete="e6 > 1" step="1">
      Select an app
      <small>Summarize if needed</small>
    </v-stepper-step>

    <v-stepper-content step="1">
      <v-card color="grey lighten-1" class="mb-12" height="200px"></v-card>
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="e6 = 2">Continue</v-btn>
      <v-btn text>Cancel</v-btn>
    </v-stepper-content>


    <v-stepper-content step="2">...</v-stepper-content>

    <v-stepper-step :complete="e6 > 3" step="3">...</v-stepper-step>

  </v-stepper>
</template>
```

horizontal (each step is separate):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-stepper>
      <v-stepper-header>
        <v-stepper-step step="1">Select campaign settings</v-stepper-step>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-stepper-step step="2">Create an ad group</v-stepper-step>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-stepper-step step="3">Create an ad</v-stepper-step>
      </v-stepper-header>
    </v-stepper>

    <v-stepper value="2" class="mt-12">
      ...
    </v-stepper>

    <v-stepper value="3" class="mt-12">
      ...
    </v-stepper>
  </div>
</template>
```